# SQL query select all rows except one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to select everything in the table `jogos` except the row where `intCategoria` is 11. How can I do that?

```
$query_GameData = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `jogos` ORDER BY  RAND()");
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer is likely `select * from `jogos` where intcategoria != 11`, however people do not like to have the impression that you did not put in effort in solving your problem yourself first. When posting your next question please describe, what you have done to solve your issue.

Comment: If that column is nullable, you have to decide whether you want the rows with NULL excluded or not. To include rows with NULL, there's several ways to do that. But, I find the (non-ANSI) null safe comparator to be useful: " `WHERE NOT (intCategoria<=>11)` "  Documented here: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `jogos`
WHERE intCategoria <> 11
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: depends on what SQL software, MS SQL it is <>

Comment: != and <> both work in MySQL as well as SQL Server.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: @DavidStetler Both `!=` and `<>` work in every major SQL server _except_ for IBM DB2 where only `<>` works. Technically, `<>` is ANSI standard, but again - both work in virtually every server.

Comment: @DavidStetler well the OP did tag the question with mysql

Comment: MySQL seems to use `!=` more often than `<>` probably because it is consistent with most other programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

Just use WHERE clause like that :

```
$query_GameData = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `jogos` where intCategoria != 11  ORDER BY RAND() ");
```